# Open Swift Playground Book

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How do i open a Swift Playground Book with Xcode or macOS? 
When i open it i get this:

[image]

Comment: check its format if it is .pub then open with apple default iBook

Comment: I want t'he playground, not the pub since I already got it

Answer (score 2):

On Xcode, go to Navigate > Reveal in Project Navigator

Answer (score 0):

A shortcut is to press cmd-alt-T. Or, as Priscila suggested, simply go to the menu and click to show the project navigator.

Answer (score 0):

You can open it using [Swift Playgrounds from Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/hu/app/swift-playgrounds/id1496833156).

Answer (score -2):

You can access to the book content by selecting the top menu and choose the content you want to display
[image: Playgroundbook example]

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.   I'm going to file a bug.